# Django + SSL + nginx + uwsgi + EC2

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

For the past couple of week's I've been trying to deploy a Django website that I made (using HTTPS everywhere) on an Redhat Amazon EC2 instance. I deployed the website using nginx and uwsgi but when I try entering the IP address of my EC2 instance I get a connection timed out. (My professor isn't going to use a hostname)

Nginx will successfully redirect me to https, but anything I've tried so far has led me to this dreaded "Connection time out, too long to respond" screen.

I've reads many tutorials online and threads on stackoverflow but have had no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

uWSGI 2.0.15 compiled with version 4.8.5 20160623 - I run the command (uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/uwsgi-django.ini)

nginx 1.12.1 - I have it setup as a service (sudo service nginx start)

Python 3.4

Django 2.0.1

My Amazon EC2 instance has port 80 and 443 open.

My Nginx configuration is as follows:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    # nginx.conf
    # Redirects any requests on port 80 (http) to https:
    server {
        server_name 35.164.X.X;
        listen  80 default_server;
        rewrite ^ https://35.164.X.X$request_uri? permanent;

        access_log /spool/nginx-redirect.log;
        error_log  /spool/nginx-redirect-error.log;
    }

    # django pass-thru via uWSGI, only from https requests:
    server {
        server_name 35.164.X.X;
        listen 443 default_server;
        ssl                 on;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/evote.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/evote.key;

        access_log /spool/nginx-access.log;
        error_log /spool/nginx-error.log;

        location / {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ec2-user/EVote/EVote.sock;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
    }
}
```

uwsgi

```
# uwsgi-django.ini
# uwsgi settings for django
[uwsgi]

# Local User
username = ec2-user

# Project Name
project = EVote

# Master
master = True

# Maximum number of processes
processes = 10

# Bind to local host
socket = /home/%(username)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664

# The base directory
chdir = /home/%(username)/%(project)/website

# Django's wsgi file
uwsgi-file= website/wsgi.py

# The virtualenv
home = /home/%(username)/virtualenv-django

# Use python3.4
PYTHON= python3.4

# Use HTTPS
env= HTTPS=on

# clear environment on exit
vacuum = True
```

My Django settings include

```
# HTTPS settings

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True

SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

SECURE_SLL_REDIRECT = True

os.environ['wsgi.url_scheme'] = 'https'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'
```

Thanks for reading.

-- Edit --
This is my Nginx-redirect Log, every other log is empty. (I removed the IP addresses in the beginning)

```
 - - [04/Feb/2018:01:15:38 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:01:16:09 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:01:16:39 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:02:56:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "curl/7.40.0"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:02:56:20 +0000] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "-"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:03:40:00 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:03:50:05 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:04:22:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:05:15:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 185 "-" "masscan/1.0 (https://github.com/robertdavidgraham/masscan)"205.251.233.161 - - [04/Feb/2018:05:37:42 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:05:39:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:05:47:08 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:05:54:22 +0000] "HEAD /phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:06:18:26 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:06:18:35 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:06:19:13 +0000] "POST /adstore/sns HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:08:30:31 +0000] "GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:10:47:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
 - - [04/Feb/2018:11:44:28 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Cloud mapping experiment. Contact research@pdrlabs.net"
```

Comment: You are sure your application is working correctly? And can you post the nginx logs?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply,

My django application works fine if I connect though a local socket on my local computer.

`python3 manage.py runserver127.0.0.1:8000`



I've also gotten it to work on the EC2 server if I don't redirect and don't use HTTPS.